# Applications or Datasets with massive number of time series

Tags: data-request, time-series

There are many applications which deal with multiple time series data such as stock market, climate change, etc. It seems most of them are dealing with a few number of streams up to 1000 series in real time. For example, I checked applications whose time series data sets are mentioned [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/large-time-series-data-for-learning), but they are not as large as I want. I am wondering if there is an application which requires to monitor tens of thousands streams in real time. It would be also good if it has a public data set of the series in a specific period.